# set an error handler for jquery datatables ajax call

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to have a custom error handler when something goes wrong (i.e. the server does not respond) on the ajax call for loading new data into my datatable.

```
$table.DataTable().ajax.url(ajaxURL).load();
```

By default it shows an alert and I can change that to throw a javascript error with the following setting:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
```

But with this, I just have an error logged to the console and I'm not sure how to catch that thrown error so I still can't provide my own error handler.

There is also an error event listed in the documentation, but that doesn't seem to get triggered, so the following never alerts.

```
$table.on( 'error', function () { alert( 'error' );} );
```

Everything else I've found so far is for the legacy code, such as setting the fnServerData, which I would like to avoid getting into.

Is there a method to set the ajax error callback in the 1.10 API?

Comment: Since ajax calls are asynchronous, it can bypass exception handling. The error probably needs to get caught in their code. You're right, the lack of an error handler is a strange omission. This is why I don't use DataTables's ajax methods. I just use the jQuery 'ajax', which does have success and error handlers, and redraw the table from scratch.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

New error event handling has been added in Datatables v1.10.5 (released 10th February **2015**).

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = function ( settings, helpPage, message ) { 
    console.log(message);
};
```

See docs here:
https://datatables.net/reference/event/error
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/

Comment: Thanks. I updated to 1.10.6 and now I am able to show a custom alert message.

Comment: Thanks. I added this to my main master blade. Every pages doesn't require datatable so I needed to wrap it with this                     `if($.fn.dataTable !== undefined){}`

Answer (score 25):

Use the Ajax error function to log errors:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        dataType: "JSON",  
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: [],
        async: true,
        error: function (xhr, error, code) {
            console.log(xhr, code);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: any way to set a global error function?

Answer (score 5):

Use the event as a custom [error handler](https://datatables.net/reference/event/error):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').on('error.dt', function (e, settings, techNote, message) {
        console.log('An error has been reported by DataTables: ', message);
    }).DataTable({
        "displayLength": 15,
        "ajax": {
          ....
```

Comment: also don't forget to add `$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';` before event to turn default error alert off

Answer (score 3):

I am using Datatables 1.10.19 + Bootstrap and most of the solutions provided (including the accepted one above) did not work. However, I managed to capture the error as follows:

```
 "ajax" : {
    "datatype" : "json",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "method" : "GET",
    "url" : $url,
    "data" : { x : y },
    "dataSrc": function (data) {
      if (data.result == "OK"){
        return data.yourObj;
      }else{
        // hide processing or any loading modal here
        // display error on page or something
        console.log("Error: " + parseResultData(data.resultData));
        data.yourObj = [] //since datatables will be checking for the object as array
        return data.yourObj;
      }                           
    } 
  }
```

Comment: I'm using DataTables 1.13.x but `dataSrc` is not called or fired when there is an error (for example HTTP 500). It will be working only success response (HTTP 200 or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

```
"ajax" : {
    "datatype" : "json",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "method" : "GET",
    "url" : $url,
    "data" : { x : y },
    "dataSrc": function (data) {
      if (data.result == "OK"){
        return data.yourObj;
      }else{
        // hide processing or any loading modal here
        // display error on page or something
        console.log("Error: " + parseResultData(data.resultData));
        data.yourObj = [] //since datatables will be checking for the object as array
        return data.yourObj;
      }                           
    } 
  }
```