# Can I use ajax success and error functions in data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use dataTable.ajax to retrieve data from rest api to render JSON data source.
[Data Table JS plugin AJAX example](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Live-examples)

I want to do

```
$("#exampleTable").DataTable({
    "ajax":{
        url:"some_api_url",
        dataSrc: "object name",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data) // to debug returned data
        },
        error: function(thrownError){
            console.log(thrownError);// to debug error
        }
    }
});
```

However, I realized that whenever I added the `success` and `error` function, the data table will have a "loading" state forever.

Are these two functions not compatible with Data table js? I used the below libraries.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: `the data table will have a "loading" state forever.` this is because you overrode the default `success` handler and your one does nothing with the response, other than log it to the console. Leave the `error` handler, and remove the `success` and the code should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ajax success function not working on datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378399/ajax-success-function-not-working-on-datatable)  Use `"dataSrc": function (json) {` instead of `success: function(data)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan answer helps me understand why I cannot have success function to see my returned data from ajax in data table. I asked the question for debugging purpose. I think I will use success  function to test the returned data format first and remove it once the response is correct to render the table.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the suggestion! I will explore that

Comment: Glad to help. I marked the question as a duplicate which contains more details. See [this specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415174/519413) in your case.