# How to correctly handle errors in jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, error-handling, datatables

I am using the (very nice) DataTable library from [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/), and I am now struggling a little with the correct handling of errors (notably a 404).

When I do nothing, I get an ugly `alert`, which I can prevent by setting this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
```

and that works fine, except I cannot catch that exception when updating the `url`, like this:

```
theTable.ajax.url(`https://some/new/updated/link`).load();
```

Then, I can use the `on` syntax:

```
theTable.on("error", function(e, settings, techNote, message) {
    // Handle the error here
    console.error('DataTables error:', techNote, message);
})
```

which seems to correctly process the error, but the exception is still raised afterwards (which works, but it clutters the console).

So, what would be the 'correct' way of handling an 404 on the url?

Comment: hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050091/set-an-error-handler-for-jquery-datatables-ajax-call